# Extra columns in powershell table

Tags: html, mysql, powershell, html-table

I have a script that reads from a MySQL database using a DataAdapter. There are three columns in the table idInstance, IPAddress and the auto id column. I only want IdInstance and IPAddress to show in report, But when I run the script and out put to table I get 7 columns the extra 5 are RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray and HasErrors.  How can I show only the 2 columns I want IdInstance and IpAddress columns.  See image of extra columns.  Moreover the output to the console is correct it only shows idinstance and ipaddress.  so it must be something in the code for building the HTML table?

```
function Execute-MySQLQuery([string]$query) { 
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $conn)    
$dataAdapter = New-Object         MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)      
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet                                   
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")                                                      
$command.Dispose()
return $dataSet.Tables["data"]                                                
}

# So, to produce a table of results from a query...
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:     black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TR:Nth-Child(Even) {Background-Color: #dddddd;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color:     black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color:  black;}

</style>
<title>
Patch Report
</title>
"@
$Pre = "<h1>Patch Report </h1>"
$Pre += "<h2>These systmes are Not Running Patch Script</h2>"
$Post = "Run on "
$Post += Get-Date

$query = " SELECT prodinstances.Idinstance, prodinstances.IPAddress
FROM prodinstances
WHERE prodinstances.Idinstance
NOT IN (select prodwinupdates.ServersId FROM prodwinupdates) order by    IPAddress ASC" 

$result = Execute-MySQLQuery $query
$strfound = ("Found " + $result.rows.count + " Systems that are not  currnetly running Patch Audit Script.")
$result  | Format-Table

          $emailSmtpServer = "mysmtpserver"
            $emailFrom = "noreply@email.com"
            $emailTo = "emailto@email.com"
            $emailSubject = $strfound
            $emailBody = $result | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post | Out-String
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServe
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the properties you want `ConvertTo-Html` to include with the `-Property` parameter:

```
$emailBody = $result | ConvertTo-HTML -Property idInstance,IPAddress -Head $Header -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post
```